# What is "Main page content" block?

Tags: commerce

what is "Main page content" block?

and why do I get "Region for Main page content block field is required."
when I disabled it?

I have commerce kickstart installed

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: I was just trying to make some sense out of it all, I was trying to remove unnecessary stuff from the home page and than I got this error...

Answer (score 1):

Main page content block is the primary content of whichever page you are viewing.

Removing does not normally make sense.